# How to automatically enter the password in your terminal using a program in PyCharm CE?

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess, passwords

So I'm pretty new to programming/coding and I have two questions.

1. What's the difference between `subprocess.run` and `subprocess.call`? Because it doesn't matter which one I use in the code below, I get the same result.
2. I'm trying to write a program using PyCharm CE to change the MAC address of my MacBook and this is the code I have so far:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("ifconfig en0 | grep ether", shell=True) #this shows me the current MAC address
subprocess.run("sudo ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", shell=True) #this changes the MAC address to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Because I've used `sudo` it's asking for my password in the terminal and I'm trying a way to find out how I can enter the password in the program without typing it in the terminal.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will work...

```
subprocess.run("echo mypassword | sudo -S ifconfig en0 ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe subprocess behaves more like a file object. You can open the subprocess, send a line, and/or ask for a line, but you can't really "monitor" the subprocess (unless you build the machinery to do that). A better module IMO, for monitoring a subprocess is the pexpect module. In this module you can open a subprocess and wait for a particular string to be returned and then send a string of information at that exact point.

input_program.py (this file should be executable by your system)

```
#!/bin/env python3
x = input('Please type a password here:')
open('password.txt','w').write(x)
```

my_program.py

```
import pexpect
sub_p = pexpect.spawn('./input_program.py')
sub_p.expect('Please type a password here:') 
sub_p.sendline('PASSWORD')
sub_p.close()
```

In this particular example, the executable saves a password to a file (just so we know the program actually ran). We then spawned that program in a subprocess which immediately printed some text (in the subprocess, we don't see the text in our current process, unless we imbed the subprocess in the current process). We then waited (this blocks until it sees the string requested), until we saw the exact bytes that told us the subprocess is ready to receive our password. We then sent the subprocess the password, PASSWORD.

In this way we have complete control to look for the bytes that the subprocess is doing. We can send a password multiple times, or answer questions the program gives us, etc. We can even imbed what the subprocess is doing into the current process allowing us to manually type in the password if we want.